# set mininum duration to loading bar

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have following:

```
isLoading$: Rx.BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(false);

 private getSomething(): void {
 this.isLoading$.next(true);
  this.http._get().subscribe((data) => {

//actions..

        },
            error => { console.log(error); },
            () => {
                 setTimeout(500);
                this.isLoading$.next(false);
            }

        );

}
```

I expect to show loading bar at least 500ms to be able to see it, because most often data is retrieved so fast that it is imposible to see loading bar.

Comment: Do you want to show the loading bar for an additional 500ms (after the request has finished), or for a minimum of 500ms?

Comment: @Caramiriel I want to show at least 500ms. Or yes,minimum.

Comment: Is it good practice to use timeout here?

Comment: Then I would suggest checking out @sabithpocker's answer. Another way would be to keep track of the remaining time yourself. If the additional 500ms doesn't bother you, `setTimeout(f, 500)` works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need to use `setTimeout` call to achieve this -

```
setTimeout(() => {
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
        // DO what else needed here
   }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` should be something like this:

```
setTimeout(() =>{
  // some code here...
  this.isLoading$.next(false);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [timer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html) and combine it with your http call using [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html). This will guarantee a minimum time set in timer, but will not add any further delay if http call already took the minimum delay.

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';

getSometing() {
    const timerSource = timer(500);
    const httpSource = this.http._get();
    const httpWithMinTimer = combineLatest(timerSource, httpSource, (t, h) => h)

   httpWithMinTimer.subscribe(data => {this.isLoading$.next(false);})
}
```